# Trying to share file with non-english characters in the name gives exception FileUriExposedException

Tags: android

When the name of the file doesnt contain arabic or unicode characters, i dont get the exception

This is the code for sharing the file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(r.getFile());
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

the Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.appbackup, PID: 2331
                  android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Apk%20Apps/%D8%A7%D8%B0%D9_1.7.0.0.apk exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
                      at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
                      at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
                      at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:832)
                      at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8909)
                      at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8894)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1517)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                      at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompatJB.java:30)
                      at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:146)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:932)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:1047)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:935)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:924)
                      at com.myapp.appbackup.fragment.RestoreFragment$3.onItemClick(RestoreFragment.java:174)
                      at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1155)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3126)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4041)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

What can be the solution for this ?

Comment: did you try this answer on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/3678308 ?\

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest not to use unicode chars in file and directory names to ensure your app is working on different android versions and various device brands.

I used `pdf` and `doc` filed with unicode and arabic content but I didn't use arabic characters for the filename. You probably don't need it too and can find a workaround to avoid it.

Comment: we cant really control what user gonna write for the name, so not using unicode chars is not the good solution at all for this. Thank you